# Incorrect output when calculating digit frequency

Tags: c

Hey guys there is a problem im occuring in this code which basically works on my compiler but the results in hacker rank shows me that the code is wrong.Please check it out.
The problem is about digit frequency.
Given a string, , consisting of alphabets and digits, find the frequency of each digit in the given string.
My code was:

```
#include<stdio.h>





int main()

{

    char str[1000];

    gets(str);
    printf("%s\n",str);// test case 1
    int a[9],i,j;//taking integers
    for(i = 0 ; i<9 ; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 0;//giving 0 value to all of the arrays
    }
    for(j = 0; str[j]!= '\0' ; j++) // main task
    {
        if(str[j] == '0')
        {
           a[0] = a[0] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '1')
        {
           a[1] = a[1] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '2')
        {
           a[2] = a[2] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '3')
        {
           a[3] = a[3] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '4')
        {
           a[4] = a[4] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '5')
        {
           a[5] = a[5] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '6')
        {
           a[6] = a[6] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '7')
        {
           a[7] = a[7] + 1;
        }
 
      else if(str[j] == '8')
        {
           a[8] = a[8] + 1;
        }
        else if(str[j]=='9')
        {
           a[9] = a[9] + 1;
        }  }
     for(i = 0 ; i<=9 ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

Result:

input (stdin)

```
73348t9895298h768464894a958zda58
```

Expected Output

```
0 0 1 2 4 3 2 2 7 5
```

I got the same output in my codeblocks compiler but still my testcases are not being succeed. Please help!

Comment: `int a[9];` defines an array with 9 elements: `a[0]`, `a[1]`, ..., and `a[8]`.

Comment: FYI "code which basically works on my compiler" is more commonly written "my code compiles". And it's superfluous - we assume that your code compiles, unless the problem you have is specifically that your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

`int a[9]` has only 9 elements, so you cannot read nor write `a[9]`.

Allocate and initialize one more element.

```
    int a[10],i,j;//taking integers (allocate one more element)
    for(i = 0 ; i<=9 ; i++) // use <= instead of <
    {
        a[i] = 0;//giving 0 value to all of the arrays
    }
```

Also note that character codes of digits are guaranteed to be continuous in C, so the part

```
        if(str[j] == '0')
        {
           a[0] = a[0] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '1')
        {
           a[1] = a[1] + 1;
        }
       else if(str[j] == '2')
        {
           a[2] = a[2] + 1;
        }
        // omit
        else if(str[j]=='9')
        {
           a[9] = a[9] + 1;
        }
```

can be written as

```
        int idx = str[j] - '0';
        if(0 <= idx && idx <= 9)
        {
           a[idx] = a[idx] + 1;
        }
```